Blenrig 6 Head Weights Transfer Problem
I am pretty new to Blender and Blenrig 6, trying to rig Silco from Arcane but when I get to step 5 of the Weights Transfer Guide, where I must add the head modifiers, adding them deforms the mouth and eyelids pretty bad, though in the guide it looks like it shouldn't affect the shape of the mesh. I also noticed that during step 4, editing the Weights Transfer Model, that the model would change a little whenever I would switch between edit and object mode.
There are two things that I wonder if they could be the issue, but I'm not sure:
1- I turned off symmetry on the model because the character's face is asymmetric
2- On step three, defining the head object, I defined the head vertex group as the head object because the head of my model is not a separate mesh
Any ideas why this could be happening and how to fix? All help is appreciated.
Before and after adding head modifiers:


Edit: After asking Blenrig 6 discord I found that for some reason the controls of the face in the reapportion stage were broken, and that I should start over. I will redo the rig and see if it works this time.
Update: I made the mesh's basis shape key symmetrical and put the asymmetry in another shape key before redoing it with complete symmetry which seems to have worked this time.
